# Array function in C

Tags: c, pointers

Nowadays I'm learning C and I have some problems with pointers. I know hoy they work but I have no idea how to use them in orden to make a function that returns an array. 
Thanks you so much!

Comment: A function can not return an array, but you can return a pointer to the first element of an array. `int *func{return &arr[0];}`, or simply `return arr;`, of course `arr` should be allocated dinamically or should be visible outside the function.

Comment: Check this pointer related guide , it's well explained - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-array-array-pointer/

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A trick to return an array is to return a struct made by an array.

```
struct struct_t
{
    int array[10];
};
struct struct_t my_var;
struct struct_t * my_fun(void)
{
    return &my_var;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!